# cloud firestore role based access example what if many readers?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

While reading the [role based access example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access#data_structure), I noticed that to be able to read the story one has to assume at least a "reader" role. So it seems that one has be first put the names of the readers in to this array before the reader can read the story.

> {   title: "A Great Story",   content: "Once upon a time ...",
> roles: {
> alice: "owner",
> bob: "reader",
> david: "writer",
> jane: "commenter"
> // ...   } }

rules:

> ```
>     // Any role can read stories.
>     allow read: if isOneOfRoles(resource, ['owner', 'writer', 'commenter', 'reader']);
> ```

This seems to be very unreal. Usually we want anyone to read the story, or, we want a lot (thousands maybe) signed in readers, in which case it is unreasonable to put all their names in the roles object in the story doc. In these cases,  can we just allow signed in users read the story?

```
allow read: request.auth != null;
```

Are there any disadvantages to this approach? What was the logic when they decided that example?